# How to center the title and the authors

Tags: titles

I have two questions.

1. How can I center the the title rather that its natural position?
2. How can I remove the date?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{ \begin{huge}
\textbf{Geometry of manifolds and differential forms} 
\end{huge} }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: `\date{}` for the second.

Comment: @title: There is no real `huge` environment. Don't use it. The title is centered horizontally. Do you mean you want it centered vertically?

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
{\centering\huge\textbf{Geometry of manifolds and differential forms} \par}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document} 
`

Comment: Standard link for the question: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Comment: If you want a title page, use report class instead of article.

Comment: What i mean is that the title is positioned in the top of the page and i want to position it in the middle of the page. @Johannes_B

Comment: The code i posted should do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would do:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \vspace*{\fill}

    \vspace*{0.5cm}

    \huge\bfseries
    Geometry of manifolds and differential forms

    \vspace*{0.5cm}

    \large Obi Wan Kenobi

    \vspace*{\fill}
    \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no `huge` environment. Please correct that.

Comment: That is strange. It does work for me. It increases size. It actually comes from autocompletion (using TexStudio). Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, i am sure. And i know it works. But it should not be used.

Comment: So by saying "it does not exist" you mean "it exist but it should not be used"? Why is that? Any reference?

Comment: Come to our chat room and ask David Carlisle. He can answer the question. I have to go now, see you. :-)

Comment: @luchonacho it is a macro misuse, the main problem here is that `text \begin{huge}text\end{huge}` is more or less the same as `text{\huge text}` thus the line spacing after `\}` is used for the entire paragraph, ignoring the huge line spacing inside.  You'll need to either add `\par` or blank lines for it to look correctly. Using say `\begin{bfseries}...\end{bfseries}` is also macro misuse as an environment, but it effect is not tied with `\par` so will work ok.

Comment: I added it manually. See answer. Choose the amount of space and the type and size of the fonts you want. Notice I added space **before and after** the title, so the centering is not lost.

Comment: `\author` only stores the data, does not print anything. As you are writing you title manually, you'll also want to add your authors manually. Otherwise switch to `\title{...} \author{...} \maketitle`